# how can i automatically generate random data for a table

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to do some sql random test, the first step is generate random data . i have the schema of the table, how can i automatically generate data

schema for example

```
    mysql> desc table_test;
+----------+-------------+------+-------+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key   | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-------+---------+-------+
| siteid   | INT         | Yes  | true  | 10      |       |
| citycode | SMALLINT    | Yes  | true  | NULL    |       |
| username | VARCHAR(32) | Yes  | true  |         |       |
| cost     | DOUBLE      | Yes  | true  | 0       |       |
| pv       | BIGINT      | Yes  | false | 0       | SUM   |
| uv       | DOUBLE      | Yes  | false | 0       | SUM   |
+----------+-------------+------+-------+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: There are websites that will automatically generate random data for you like filldb.info. Search up "automatically create random data for mysql table" and hit the first link or two.

Answer (score 1):

In this page

```
http://filldb.info/dummy
```

you can generate code with the schema of table. Later you can download it.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. but i want to generate more data like 1b rows for my database test framework. it's there any open source project doing so?